# Netbeans IDE and expanded watches while debugging Java project

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, ide

I'm debugging one of my java project in Netbeans IDE. I need to know what contains some variables **inside** and that's the reason why I expand some watches. Expansion is not permanent and IDE canceled it after a few steps and I must to click *+* symbols to restore it. It's uncomfortable and time consuming. Any idea how to fix it?
Thank you.

EDIT:
I have an ArrayList *noveUzly* in Watches. After starting debuger I only see 'nove Uzly  | "size = 5"' in debug window. Then I click ***+*** symbol (to see what is inside this variable). After that I step my program. Netbeans IDE close all my variables automatically back (to 'nove Uzly  | "size = 5"') after several steps (e.g. step into a for loop). 
**What I want?**  Set Netbeans to do not close my expanded variables.

[image]

Comment: Add a custom watch containing an expression

Comment: It's a way how to do it but it's not exactly what I want. When nobody doesn't know something better I'll use it.

Comment: What should I do when I want to see content of a ArrayList? Something like list.get(1) is not effective (list can have 1, 10, 25, ... items).

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. Why list.get(1) is not effective?

Comment: Something like list.get(1) is not enought. During stepping program has list size 10, than 25 etc. Having 25 lines with like list.get(1) is chaotic (and each item list.get(x) should be expanded to next four subitems). So I set by clicking **+** symbol what I need at this moment and I want to maintain this state.